# How to translate in twig from php

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I tried to integrate an ads on my website. So in there documentation is writing to show the ads need to do :

```
echo captchme_generate_html($publicKey);
```

Now I use twig template, and I'm do in controller :

```
$this->captch_me_template =  captchme_generate_html(self::CAPTCH_ME_PUBLIC_KEY);
```

And in template I do :

```
{{ captch_me_template }}
```

And in template I get as result :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.captchme.net/api/script?key=dfgfd3454.....
```

And I don't understand where is the problem. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, it's necessare to add a raw `{{ captch_me_template|raw }}`